# Haskell - error in download code

Tags: http, haskell, download

```
downloadCSVFile ::String-> IO (Bool,String)
downloadCSVFile company_code = do 
    let a="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" ++ company_code
    let b=simpleHTTP $  getRequest a 
    src <- ( b >>= getResponseBody)
    rcode <- fmap rspCode <$> b
    h <- fmap findHeader HdrLocation   b

    case rcode of
        Left   err    ->  return (False, "Connection error: " ++ show err)
        Right (2,_,_) -> return (True,src)
        Right (4,_,_) -> return  (False,"Invalid URL/The requested page does not exist..")
        Right (5,_,_) -> return  (False, "Internal error in the server on trying to process the request") 
        Right (3,_,_) ->    
            case h  of 
                Nothing -> return (False, "Error : " )
                Just url -> downloadCSVFile a
```

Please help me to resolve the following error and help me to check whether I've included all the condition in the "case" statement or not:

[image]

Comment: Do not edit out your question content or delete your questions like this. It is not at all fair to those who have spent time answering your question. If you don't want your code here, *don't post it here in the first place*.

Answer (score 2):

You've got several problems in your code.  The first is your return type.  You're trying to encode the notion of failure or success using a tuple and a string.  Instead, you could use the `Either` type to handle this much more elegantly

```
downloadCSVFile :: String -> IO (Either String String)
downloadCSVFile company_code = do
    let url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" ++ company_code
```

Next, you use `let b = simpleHTTP $ getRequest a`.  You're assigning an IO action inside an `IO` function, when instead you should be extracting the result using `<-`

```
    response <- simpleHTTP $ getRequest url
```

This lets you write the next few lines without duplicate `fmap`s (`<$>` is the infix form of `fmap`, so you're `fmap`-ing multiple times unnecessarily)

```
    src <- getResponseBody response
    let rcode = fmap rspCode response
        header = fmap findHeader HdrLocation response
```

And now we come across what seems to be the culprit.  Your use of `fmap findHeader HdrLocation response` is incorrect.  What you meant was `fmap (findHeader HdrLocation) response`, the parentheses are very important here.

Since we're now using the `Either` type, we have to change our case statement a bit, but it's certainly cleaner now.  We use the convention `Left` for errors and `Right` for success.  This is exactly how the `Network.HTTP` library works with the `Result` type.

```
    case rcode of
        Left err        -> return $ Left $ "Connection error: " ++ show err
        Right (2, _, _) -> return $ Right src
        Right (4, _, _) -> return $ Left "Invalid URL..."
        Right (5, _, _) -> return $ Left "Internal error in the server..."
        Right (3, _, _) ->
            case header of
                Nothing   -> return $ Left "Error"
                Just url' -> downloadCSVFile $ fromJust $ parseURI url
```

---

To sum up, the real problem was with the line

```
h <- fmap findHeader HdrLocation <$> b
```

for its lack of parentheses that would have made it correct.  We also looked into using `do` notation to our advantage to avoid superfluous `fmap`s, and also assuring the correct behavior of the program.  By defining `b = simpleHTTP $ getRequest a`, you were assigning `b` to that action, but not to it's result.  Depending on the compiler or platform, that could mean that every time you used `b`, it could be trying to download that URL again.  That is obviously bad, since any one of them could fail, it eats up bandwidth, and hits the yahoo server harder than need be.  Finally, we examined how we can use the `Either` data type for more elegant error handling.  It's certainly possible that you might want to add another case to `case rcode of` in which you accidentally return `(True, "Some error message")` instead of `(False, "Some error message")`, in which case you could crash your program!  By delimiting ourselves with `Left` and `Right`, we remove another point of failure.

Comment: returning a tuple which contains a boolean value and the string is a must. Can you change the code in a way it produces such an output ?

Comment: @user3032393 I think it'd be pretty simple to convert every `Left ...` into `(False, ...)` and `Right ...` into `(True, ...)`.